# Macro for coroutines

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

I try to achieve some very rudimentary multi tasking with coroutines. The target platform is an AVR microcontroller so I am tight on memory and can not do a lot of fancy stuff. The idea that I am following was described here: [Coroutines in C (Simon Tatham)](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html)

However this approach uses switch statements and static gotos. I would prefer computed gotos instead. Thus I came up with the following piece of code.

```
void static_parse(const char c) {
    static void * parser_state = &&l_parser_start;
    goto *parser_state;
    #define WAIT_FOR_NEXT_CHAR parser_state = &&label ## __LINE__ ; return; label ## __LINE__ : ;
    l_parser_start:

    // do some stuff with first character

    WAIT_FOR_NEXT_CHARACTER;
    // do some stuff with second character

    WAIT_FOR_NEXT_CHARACTER;
    // do some stuff with third character

    l_done:
    parser_state = &&l_parser_start;
    return;
```

My idea is to extract the label's address and keep this in a static variable. The caller is responsible to push a character to this coroutine whenever a new charcater is available. Unfortunately this does not work. The compiler complains

```
test.cpp:73:1: error: duplicate label ‘label__LINE__’
test.cpp:76:1: error: duplicate label ‘label__LINE__’
```

Obviously the idea to get different labels with the help of the `__LINE__` macro fails because `__LINE__` does not get expanded. I tried different preprocessor tricks but each attempt so far failed.

Another unsucessful attempt was

```
    static void * parser_state = &&l_parser_start;
    goto *parser_state;
    #define INNER(N) parser_state = &&label ## N ; return; label ## N : ;
    #define WAIT_FOR_NEXT_CHAR INNER(__LINE__)
    l_parser_start:
```

How can I generate labels that look like label_nnnn where nnnn is the current line number? Or how can I generate unique labels in a different way? Of course I could pass the desired label names into the macro but I would prefer to avoid this.

Comment: you have to stringify

Comment: Why would this help? I still do not get it.

Comment: According to the documentation:  "Sometimes you may want to convert a macro argument into a string constant. Parameters are not replaced inside string constants, but you can use the ‘#’ preprocessing operator instead. When a macro parameter is used with a leading ‘#’, the preprocessor replaces it with the literal text of the actual argument, converted to a string constant. Unlike normal parameter replacement, the argument is not macro-expanded first. This is called stringification."  --> stringification is probably the last thing that I want.

Comment: LOL. You posted a solution where you do stringification. Make up your mind.

Comment: The documentation (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) says:  Sometimes you may want to convert a macro argument into a string constant. ...  Unlike normal parameter replacement, the argument is not macro-expanded first. This is called stringification. -- I do not want to get a string constant, I want to concatenate a macro expansion to get a label.

Comment: The documentation (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan) says: Macro arguments are completely macro-expanded before they are substituted into a macro body, unless they are stringified or pasted with other tokens. ... ... If an argument is stringified or concatenated, the prescan does not occur. If you want to expand a macro, then stringify or concatenate its expansion, you can do that by causing one macro to call another macro that does the stringification or concatenation.

Comment: My conclusions are: 1) what I have is called "concentation" by the documentation. 2) The expansion of `__line__` behaves as if `__line__` is an argument in the sense of the documentation. I verified that this happens with any macro. My conclusion would be that the documentation is imprecise at best or my preprocessor does not stick to the documentation. Another conclusion is that I do not understand the fine print because I am not a native speaker. This is why I inquire.

Answer (score 1):

By now I found a solution

```
    static void * parser_state = &&l_parser_start;
    goto *parser_state;
    #define LABEL(N) label_ ## N
    #define XLABEL(N) LABEL(N)
    #define WAIT_FOR_NEXT_CHAR parser_state = &&XLABEL(__LINE__) ; return; XLABEL(__LINE__) : ;

    l_parser_start: ;
```

The solution is basically a copy of the documentation for [Argument Prescan](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescanhttps://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan). However I have no real clue why the other attempts failed. So I would still be happy if someone could explain why the other macros do not expand `__LINE__` as I would haved expected.

Comment: ["There is no way to convert a macro argument into a character constant. If you want to stringify the result of expansion of a macro argument, you have to use two levels of macros."](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html)